# Why vim can't find a word in a js buffer when autocompletting?

Tags: autocompletion

I have a unnamed buffer and a js buffer open in a vertical split.

In the unnamed buffer I'm trying to type an already existing function name. In the js buffer I typed two characters, but when I `<c-x><c-n>`, it shows:

```
Keyword Local completion (^N^P) Pattern not found
```

My `complete` option is set like this:

```
 complete=.,w,b,u,t,i,U,k
```

Comment: Did you even read `:help compl-current`?

Comment: When I tried this, If I opened a new split *after* the one I was wanting to complete from it worked. If I opened the new buffer first, I get your result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the `complete` option is ignored by `<C-x><C-n>` so its value is irrelevant.

Second, `<C-x><C-n>` only completes from the current buffer, as explained in `:h ins-completion`:

```
2. keywords in the current file             |i_CTRL-X_CTRL-N|
```

and `:help compl-current`:

```
Completing keywords in current file         *compl-current*
```

If you want to complete from other buffers, use `<C-n>` or `<C-p>`.